# User Authorize and twice fetch request problem on react

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am a net developer and on my first react project i need help. My Problems :
**1-** RequireAuth function is not waiting until fetch data from server side.
**2-** fetch is sending twice request to my api project builded by .netcore. When i check it by postman, there is not problem.
Thanks for your helps.

**App.js**

```
import {Home as MainHome} from './Views/Home';
import {Home as PanelHome} from './Panel/Views/Home';
import {Login} from './Panel/Views/login';
import{getCookie} from './Panel/Controllers/cookie.js';
import { variables } from './Panel/Controllers/Variables.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes,Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
return (
<div className="App contanier">
<Router>         
<Routes>        
    <Route path='/' element={<MainHome/>}/>
    <Route path='/panel/login' element={<Login/>}/>
    <Route path='/panel' element={
    <RequireAuth redirectTo="/panel/login"> 
    <PanelHome/>
    </RequireAuth>
    }/>
  </Routes>  
</Router>
</div>
);
}

function RequireAuth ({ children, redirectTo }) {
let isAuthenticated =GetAuth(); 
return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}

function GetAuth(){
const cookie= getCookie();
let IsOk=false;
if (!cookie){
return  IsOk;
}
else{
fetch(variables.API_URL+'Auth',{
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
 },      
  body:JSON.stringify({
      token:cookie
  })
})   
.then(res=>res.json())
.then((result)=>{
 IsOk=result.Ok;    
 },(error)=>{      
  console.log(error);
 })
return IsOk;
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

may help to try this:

```
 function RequireAuth ({ children, redirectTo }) { 
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuth] = useState('')
    async function handleAuth(){
       try{
         const res = await GetAuth()
         setIsAuth(res.isOK)}
       catch(e){console.error(e)}}
    useEffect(()=>{
        handleAuth()
    },[])
    return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />; }
```

also your calling getCookies twice

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).

Comment: im sorry friend i hav'nt notice that your using this function as a component,
you can maybe try somthing like this - 
    f

Comment: unction RequireAuth ({ children, redirectTo }) {
           const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuth] = useState('')
           GetAuth().then((res)=>{
            setIsAuth(res.isOK)
            }).catch((e)=>console.error(e)) 
            return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}

Comment: i've put it more clear on the original comment, hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks your response I got App.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: GetAuth(...).then is not a function also fetch twice problem continue

Comment: have you seen the last edit with useEffect and async?

Comment: I implement now and "Missing semicolon." on row "async handleAuth(){"

Comment: add "function" between async and function-
like this -->
async function handleAuth(){

Comment: Thanks for your effort for me.  Twice fetch requests handled. But still not waiting fetch response true or false. Also got error Warning: ---Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.---

Comment: can you send here the login component?

Comment: Thank you so much. I handle error by change res.isOK to res. Also I changed GetAuth() function to async function. Now everything is working fine. For me this is a big step on react and you helped to much for pass. Thank you again.